# RのCSVデータの取り込みについて

Tags: r

MacOSでのRの取り扱いにについて質問です。

メニューバーより「その他 → 作業ディレクトリの変更」からCSVデータを選択しようと思っているのですが、グレーアウトしておりデータを選択できません。

どなたか解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらお伺いできませんでしょうか。
お手数をおかけしますがよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

作業ディレクトリの変更 というのは，文字通り自分が今作業しているディレクトリを変更するためのメニュー項目なので，CSV の読み込みはできません．

コンソールに `getwd()` と入力した結果が今作業中のディレクトリで，これを変更するためのメニューです．

CSV の読み込みは，

```
read.csv()
```

という関数を使います．

別途インストールが必要ですが，R.app ではなく RStudioというソフトを使えば，CSVを読み込むメニューがあります（File > Import Dataset > From CSV）．

Answer (score 0):

「作業ディレクトリの変更」で直接csvファイルを選ぶのではなくcsvファイルが入っているディレクトリを選んで`df <- read.csv("hogehoge.csv")`などで読み込んでください。

ちなみに作業ディレクトリの変更はコマンドだと`setwd("ディレクトリのパス")`となっています。

発展編としてもう少し付け加えさせていただきますとファイルが大きくて読み込みに時間がかかる場合は`data.table`パッケージの`fread()`関数や`readr`や`tidyverse`パッケージに入っている`read_csv()`関数などだと読み込み速度がかなり早くなります。